# Passing references to Spring managed beans to non-managed classes?

Tags: java, spring

If I have something like a jdbcTemplate that is created and managed by Spring, am I able to take that reference and pass it down to a non-spring managed class?

If I can, how do life cycle methods such as @PreDestory know if there are now these extra references which are not known to Spring floating around?

Comment: I think at this point the life cycle will be inherited from the caller wrapper method which is managed by Spring, assuming you are passing it through method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singleton beans managed by spring are retained in the application context.
You can think about the Application Context as a map that stores key like "id" to objects that are essentially references to the beans you have.

Now you can easily pass the reference to the bean to some object not managed by spring.

class NonManagedBySpring  {
      private JdbcTemplate tpl;
      public NonManagedBySpring(JdbcTemplate tpl) {
          this.tpl = tpl;
      }

```
  public void bar() {
   ...
   tpl.execute // or whatever
  }
}


@Service // this is a spring managed service
class MyService {
  @Autowired // or constructor injection, doesn't matter for the sake of this example
  private JdbcTemplate tpl;

  public void foo() {
       NonManagedBySpring  obj = new NonManagedBySpring (tpl);
       obj.bar();
  }    
}
```

Now, from the point of view of lifecycle, it doesn't matter that `NonManagedBySpring` holds the reference on `JdbcTemplate` object which is a bean.

When the `@PreDestroy` should be called, spring checks the reference in `ApplicationContext`, and since as I stated at the beginning of the answer, there is a reference to singleton beans - spring will find these objects and invoke a "pre-destroy" on it.

Having said that it worth to mention that if the bean is of scope "prototype" it won't be held on Application Context and its `@PreDestroy` won't be called anyway, but that has nothing to do with the managed/non-managed objects. That's just how the spring works.